# output is not what is expected (Tue Aug 20 07:52:00 IST 2019 )

Tags: java, katalon-studio

The output should be the same as

> (dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm)

but could see

> "Tue Aug 20 07:52:00 IST 2019"

```java
String[] tokens = lastupdated.split(": | \\(");
Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").parse(tokens[1]);
System.out.println(date1);
```

Comment: what is the value for `lastupdated`

Comment: What is `lastupdated`?

Comment: it is string value like "Mubasher Last Update Time: 20-Aug-2019 07:42 (GMT)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `println date1` is not a valid java syntax, you should use `System.out.println()`

Second thing is if you want to print the date in `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm` format then you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` **[format](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-change-date-format-in-a-string/)** function

Try this out

```
String lastupdated = "Mubasher Last Update Time: 20-Aug-2019 07:42 (GMT)";
String[] tokens = lastupdated.split(": | \\(");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm");
Date date = sdf.parse(new String(tokens[1]));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

**Output**

```
20-Aug-2019 07:42
```

Answer (score 1):

You should print your date with a custom format

```java
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("(dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm)").format(date1));
// First you parse the String, then you display with a custom format
```

Otherwise Java will use standard format during print

Answer (score 1):

When you call `System.out.println(date1)`, the `toString()` method of `java.util.Date` gets called to form the string representation of the date.
As per [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--), this will print the date in a format **"dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy"**

If you want to format the date to a string in the format you need, then you should use the `format` method to make it in the string mode you need.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = ..//
String formattedString = dateFormat.format(date); //..
```